# What is the difference between "what is the good of?" and "what is the use of?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, phrase-choice, idioms-in-context

My question is and I would like to know, is there any difference in the meaning between the sentences "what is the Good of?" and "What is the use of ?"
In order to make this clear,  I can construct one sentence, which reads "what is the good of [or what is the use of?"] registering or signing up in other three cities besides my own city regarding payment of property taxes, if I can't engineer riots? Though I am not the mastermind. I am a newcomer in this city from non-urban areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasal uses, incomplete sentences are, "What is the good of" means if as a result, anything will turn out to be beneficial for us. "What is the use of" implies doubt about whether we will achieve anything positive that we need.